# Very slow batching update with MySQL .Net/Connector 6.5.4/6.6.4

Tags: c#, mysql

I am using MySQL5.6.9-rc with .net connector 6.5.4 to insert data into a table that has two fields (Interger ID, Integer Data, ID is the primary key). It is very slow (about 35 seconds) to insert 2000 rows into the table (no much difference for UpdateBatchSize = 1 and UpdateBatchSize = 500), I also tried connector 6.6.4, the problem remains.

However it is fast with MySQL5.4.3 and connector 6.20, it just took one second to insert 2000 rows to the table if sets UpdateBatchSize to 500 (it's also slow if UpdateBatchSize = 1). then I tested it with MySQL5.4.3 and connector 6.5.4 or 6.6.4, it is slow!

I wrote the code to insert data like below, run it with mysql6.6.9 and connector 6.54, Windows XP and VS2008.

```
    public void Test()
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Database=myDatabase;Server=localhost;User Id=root;Password=myPassword");

        string sql = "Select * from myTable";
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);

        adapter.UpdateBatchSize = 500; 

        MySqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter);

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(table); //it is an empty table
        Add2000RowsToTable(table);

        int count = adapter.Update(table); //It took 35 seconds to complete.
        adapter.Dispose();
        conn.Close();
    }


    private void Add2000RowsToTable(DataTable table)
    {
        DataRow row;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
        {
            row = table.NewRow();
            row[0] = i;
            row[1] = i;

            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
```

It seems to me that MySqlDataAdapter.UpdateBatchSize is not functional with connector 6.5.4 and 6.64, is something wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Although this takes a bit of initial coding (and doesn't solve your issue directly), I highly recommend using [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) for anything longer than maybe 100 records.

*In fact, in my own system, I've coded it once and I reuse it for all my inserts and updates, whether bulk or not.*

`LOAD DATA INFILE` is much more scalable: I've used it to insert 100 million rows without noticeable performance degradation.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll try it if the issue cannot be solved soon. Actually I don't need to load huge data, and I prefer the update process under an external transaction.

Comment: @Tony fwiw, it appears that you can wrap it in a transaction:  http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=11151 though I've never tried it myself.  gl.

Answer (score 1):

Did more test...

Check the logs in mysql server, for connector 6.20, it generates the sql statements for batching updates like below:

insert into mytable (id, data) values (0,0),(1,1),(2,2) ...

but for connector 6.54 and 6.64, the statements are different:

insert into mytable (id, data) values (0,0); Insert into mytable (id, data) values (1,1);Insert into mytable (id, data) values (2,2); ...

I think this is the reason why batching update is so slow with connector 6.5.4/6.6.4, is it a bug for 6.5.4/6.6.4? or the server (tried mysql 5.5.29/5.6.9) should handle the statements more smart?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I went with was to write the bulk row data as CSV into a file and then import using the following command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  'C:/path/to/file.csv'
INTO TABLE <tablename>
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(<field1>,<field2>);
```

only took about 4 seconds for 30000 rows. It's similar to the above recommendation, but allows you to use a file local to your system and not the server.